# Why alternate background color in SSRS on a matrix reflects on more than 1 row

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

For some reason alternate background in matrix covers more then one row.

[image]

**My Row Group:**

[image]

I would expect it to behaive like this:

[image]

This is the expression I use:

```
= IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "AliceBlue", "Transparent")
```

Comment: It's working fine with above formula in table report. Do you want the same in Matrix report?

Comment: Edit your question and show the report design and row groups. RowNumber() is scope based so if the scope was set to the dataset for example, the same row number might be applicable to more than a single row in the matrix.

Comment: @Soundappan A . Yes, I need that for matrix

Comment: @Alan Schofield  Thanks. So what should I set the Scope of the ROWNUMBER() in my case?

Comment: Try my below answer.. it will give desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Check this below sample screenshot and steps. It will give desired output


[Sample Report Preview[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Httkc.jpg)

[Sample Report Design[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af4RY.jpg)

**Steps :**

1. Create sample matrix report
2. Create the new column outside the group right
3. In newly created column's textbox `named` as `txtRowNumber`, set the `value` to `RowNumber(Nothing)` and column `visibility` to `Hide`
4. In Matrix column's textbox set the fill value to `IIF(ReportItems!txtRowNumber.Value Mod 2 =0,"Green","Transparent")`.
5. Preview the report and change the design and so on.

Comment: Tanks. I followed your suggestion but still same behavior

Comment: It just setting of TextBox’s RowNumber out of all scope, then setting background value with TextBox’s value. Provide your sample design and formula to more clear.